# How can I prepare my data from multiple time series sources for time series regression?

Tags: keras, time-series, feature-engineering, lstm, cnn

I have multiple sensors providing time series sources with slightly different time stamps and different sampling rates. For example I have a breathing rate feature from 1 sensor at 1 Hz, EKG from another at 100 Hz and temperature for another at 10Hz.

If I were to use this data with a 1D CNN or LSTM, how would I prepare it? I tried resampling all the sources to 10Hz and merging them by closest timestamp but that didn’t work out too well. What are common methods of tackling this problem?